# Limiting the number of simultaneously executing tasks

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Consider this a huge pool of tasks:

```
var tasks = new Task[4]
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething())
    };

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

What if I only wanted to run say 3 tasks simultaneously? How would I implement that in code?

Comment: In general you can leave that to the TPL scheduler. Do you have a good reason to interfere?

Comment: I agree in general. However, in my concrete usecase there is a requirement to handle throttling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A less complicated example than the MSDN version would be to use Parallel.Invoke setting the max degree of parallelism:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, 
    () => DoSomething(), 
    () => DoSomething(),
    () => DoSomething(),
    () => DoSomething(),
    () => DoSomething());
```

Parallel.Invoke() will however block until all parallel operations are finished (meaning that no code beyond the parallel.invoke will run until they are all completed). If this doesn't work for you then you will end up needing to create your own task scheduler as is shown is the MSDN article linked by Daniel.

Comment: About the blocking: This statement will _always_ block until all tasks are completed, nothing to do with MaxDegeree.

Comment: I am sorry if it sounded like that is what i meant, your are 100% correct, i did not mean that maxdegreeofparallelism is what caused the blocking - post updated to make it more clear what i meant hopefully

Answer (score 8):

I found [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) on MSDN. I believe it implements what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to specify number of simultaneous tasks. Be warned that this is a bad design idea - at least in most cases you should let the system decide how many tasks to execute simultaneously. When you use `Task.Factory.StartNew` method to create tasks this way without additional parameters, they are meant to be executed ASAP (as soon as possible), so you are generally not supposed to explicitly specify the number for their simultaneous execution.

What does mean ASAP in this case? The task manager will decide if it will start all of them immediately, or jsut some of them, or wait for some other tasks to finish, etc.

You can use some kind of a manual synchornization to achieve your goal. I mean like a semaphore. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

If you don't need to do other work and want just to wait for the tasks to be completed, I would prefer `Parallel.Invoke` as suggeted by Gary S.

Comment: How did you decide this kind of task is meant to be execute ASAP? It is completely impossible some kind of requirement could require something else?

Comment: The reason is that you use StartNew without any special parameters. Tasks created this way are run as soon as possible. I rewrote my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[My blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/limit-the-number-of-c-tasks-that-run-in-parallel/) shows how to do this both with Tasks and with Actions, and provides a sample project you can download and run to see both in action.

The original poster did not specify if they preferred using Actions or Tasks, and sometimes it is not easy to switch from one to the other, so I present both solutions here.

## With Actions

If using Actions, you can use the built-in .Net Parallel.Invoke function. Here we limit it to running at most 3 threads in parallel.

```
var listOfActions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Note that we create the Action here, but do not start it.
    listOfActions.Add(() => DoSomething());
}

var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3};
Parallel.Invoke(options, listOfActions.ToArray());
```

## With Tasks

Since you are using Tasks here though, there is no built-in function. However, you can use the one that I provide on my blog.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        StartAndWaitAllThrottled(tasksToRun, maxTasksToRunInParallel, -1, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutInMilliseconds">The maximum milliseconds we should allow the max tasks to run in parallel before allowing another task to start. Specify -1 to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, int timeoutInMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        // Convert to a list of tasks so that we don&#39;t enumerate over it multiple times needlessly.
        var tasks = tasksToRun.ToList();

        using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasksToRunInParallel))
        {
            var postTaskTasks = new List<Task>();

            // Have each task notify the throttler when it completes so that it decrements the number of tasks currently running.
            tasks.ForEach(t => postTaskTasks.Add(t.ContinueWith(tsk => throttler.Release())));

            // Start running each task.
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                // Increment the number of tasks currently running and wait if too many are running.
                throttler.Wait(timeoutInMilliseconds, cancellationToken);

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                task.Start();
            }

            // Wait for all of the provided tasks to complete.
            // We wait on the list of "post" tasks instead of the original tasks, otherwise there is a potential race condition where the throttler&#39;s using block is exited before some Tasks have had their "post" action completed, which references the throttler, resulting in an exception due to accessing a disposed object.
            Task.WaitAll(postTaskTasks.ToArray(), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And then creating your list of Tasks and calling the function to have them run, with say a maximum of 3 simultaneous at a time, you could do this:

```
var listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var count = i;
    // Note that we create the Task here, but do not start it.
    listOfTasks.Add(new Task(() => Something()));
}
Tasks.StartAndWaitAllThrottled(listOfTasks, 3);
```