# Start a fixed number of process using C#

Tags: c#, process

I want to run say 50 processes but since the machine will choke at 5, I want to run 5 processes at a time and and keep starting the next one as soon as one of the 5 running processes finish.  Please advice what's a good way to do this?

I can wait on the last process I launch by Process.WaitForExit  but that doesn't do the trick since what if one of the earlier 4 processes finishes first.

Thanks

Comment: Answered here -> [limiting-simultaneous-tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774995/limiting-the-number-of-simultaneously-executing-tasks)

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a similar bottleneck while writing an app to handle hundreds of Powershell commands. I ended up creating a "queue" class that contained a list of objects. The objects were another custom class that contained the Process and a few events.

I'd loop through the processes, setting them up to be run, then add them to the Queue class. At the end I'd call a RunFirstScripts function that looped through the first 20 in the list and called a Start function, then removed it from the list.

I bound the Exit event to a handler that ran the next server and then removed it from the queue.

```
class ServerQueue
    {
        private List<Script> Servers = new List<Script>();

        public void Add(Script Server)
        {
            Servers.Add(Server);
            Server.Exited += cmd_Exited;
        }

        public void RunNextScript()
        {
            if (Servers.Count > 0)
            {
                Script ToRun = Servers[0];
                Servers.Remove(ToRun);
                ToRun.StartProcess();
            }
        }

        public void StartFirstScripts()
        {
            byte Running = 0;
            while (Servers.Count > 0 && Running <= 20)
            {
                RunNextScript();
                Running++;
            }
        }

        private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunNextScript();
        }
    }
```

EDIT Here's some code for the Script:

```
class Script
    {

        public string Output
        {
            get
            {
                return pOutput;
            }
        }

        public string Errors
        {
            get
            {
                return pErrors;
            }
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get
            {
                return pIsRunning;
            }
        }

        private string pOutput = "";
        private string pErrors = "";
        private bool pIsRunning = false;

        public delegate void OutputEventHandler(Script sender, string Output, bool IsError);

        public delegate void StatusEventHandler(Script sender);

        public event OutputEventHandler OutputDataReceived;
        public event OutputEventHandler ErrorDataReceived;
        public event StatusEventHandler Started;
        public event StatusEventHandler Exited;

        private Process cmd;

        public void StartProcess()
        {
            pIsRunning = true;
            cmd.Start();
            cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
            cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
            Started(this);
        }

        public void KillProcess()
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                cmd.Kill();
            }
        }

        public void SetupScript()
        {
            cmd = new Process();

            //configure Process (but don't start it yet)
        }

        private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pIsRunning = false;
            Exited(this);

            //do other stuff
        }

        private void cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            OutputDataReceived(this, e.Data, false);

            //do stuff
        }

        private void cmd_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            ErrorDataReceived(this, e.Data, true);

            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

There's a tiny race condition, if the planets align correctly you could attempt to start the same process twice but the second attempt should fail (as it's already running) and the way it's set up it's extremely unlikely to ever occur. You can add some extra error trapping if you like, there should probably be a try/catch in StartProcess (this is modified from my own solution and as such missing some context).

EDIT
Here is my Process to work with all these bits:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-executionpolicy unrestricted -file \"" + TempFile.FullName + "\" -pwd " + Pwd;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived += cmd_UpdateDataReceived;
        cmd.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_ErrorDataReceived;
        cmd.Exited += cmd_Exited;
```

Comment: When is cmd_Exited of Script called? That is the most important signal that I am missing Also, I believe the signature was a typo:        public delegate void StatusEventHandler(Script sender, EventArgs e);

Comment: cmd_Exited is called when the Process closes, either by completing and closing or by calling `Process.Kill()`. Note that some processes like Powershell.exe and cmd.exe will NOT close if you are using `Process.RedirectStandardInput` so you either have to get it to kill itself somehow or have `RedirectStandardInput` set to `false`.

StatusEventHandler was only used to advise my form the process had terminated so there were no other arguments apart from `Sender` I wanted to send. You can add `e` if you like but it's not really necessary.

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as so =) I still need enough rep to comment (apart from on my own posts) lol.

Comment: Oh you also need to set `cmd.EnableRaisingEvents` to `true` for it to trigger events properly. I'll add my cmd bits to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is the edited code for completeness.  Full credit to Deadly-Bagel.  Thanks,

```
class ServerQueue
{
    private List<Script> Servers = new List<Script>();

    public void Add(Script Server)
    {
        Servers.Add(Server);
        Server.Exited += cmd_Exited;
    }

    public void RunNextScript()
    {
        if (Servers.Count > 0)
        {
            Script ToRun = Servers[0];
            Servers.Remove(ToRun);
            ToRun.StartProcess();
        }
    }

    public void StartFirstScripts()
    {
        byte Running = 0;
        while (Servers.Count > 0 && Running <= 20)
        {
            RunNextScript();
            Running++;
        }
    }

    private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunNextScript();
    }
}


class Script
{

    public string Output
    {
        get
        {
            return pOutput;
        }
    }

    public string Errors
    {
        get
        {
            return pErrors;
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return pIsRunning;
        }
    }

    private string pOutput = "";
    private string pErrors = "";
    private bool pIsRunning = false;

    public delegate void OutputEventHandler(Script sender, string Output, bool IsError);

    public delegate void StatusEventHandler(Script sender, EventArgs e);

    public event OutputEventHandler OutputDataReceived;
    public event OutputEventHandler ErrorDataReceived;
    public event StatusEventHandler Started;
    public event StatusEventHandler Exited;

    private Process cmd;

    public void StartProcess()
    {
        pIsRunning = true;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
        Started(this, null);
    }

    public void KillProcess()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            cmd.Kill();
        }
    }

    public void SetupScript()
    {
        cmd = new Process();
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);

        //configure Process (but don't start it yet)
    }

    private void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pIsRunning = false;
        Exited(this, null);

        //do other stuff
    }

    private void cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        OutputDataReceived(this, e.Data, false);

        //do stuff
    }

    private void cmd_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorDataReceived(this, e.Data, true);

        //do stuff
    }
}
```